# Como resolver o erro 405 método não permitido no servidor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu desenvolvi uma web api, subir no servidor é de todos os métodos o único que não funciona é o excluir, fiz uma pesquisa na internet é descobrir:

Quando você procura o documento padrão, você recebe uma das seguintes mensagens de erro:
Erro de HTTP
O método especificado na linha de solicitação não é permitido para o recurso identificado pela solicitação. Certifique-se de que você tenha o MIME adequado digite configurar para o recurso solicitado.
Se o problema persistir, contate o administrador do servidor.
HTTP 405 - recurso não permitido
Serviços de informações da Internet
Esse problema ocorre se as seguintes condições forem verdadeiras:
Você não especificar o nome do arquivo. Por exemplo, você não especificar http://Server/Web/.
O modelo de objeto script (SOM) está habilitado.
Um evento DTC é chamado.

Na máquina local tudo funciona, apenas no servidor não está funcionando.

Se você poder me dar uma ajuda na solução, agradeço

Comment: Olá, você tem acesso ao web.config do site? tenta adicionar isso  dentro de SYSTEM.WEBSERVER   <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> <!-- ADD THIS -->
    </modules>

Comment: Eu fechei a outra pergunta como duplicata desta, já que a resposta já está aqui.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu nunca vi isto antes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/107112/edit o que será que houve?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pra mim está habilitado, já que sou mod. Mas a pergunta foi bloqueada pelo sistema porque foi fechada após eu ter migrado do meta. Isso configura uma "migração rejeitada" e bloqueia a pergunta.

Comment: Sistema é bem esperto e automatizado mesmo, até sabe o "caminho que a pergunta fez", apesar que deveria só acontecer isto em alguns tipos de fechamento, ainda sim obrigado pelo esclarecimento !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução do problema.
Não sei o porque quando se utiliza [HttpDelete], localmente funciona mais quando você vai usar isso em um servidor remoto vai gera este erro 405.

A solução foi altera para [HttpPost], o resultado final da no mesmo, agora esta funcionando.

```html
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("deletar/jogo/{nJogo}/{idusuario}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Deletar(int nJogo, int idusuario)
        {
            try
            {
                var tTabela = new JogoDetalheAplicacao();
                tTabela.Excluir(nJogo, idusuario);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Cadastro excluido.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```